# Select unable to select initial value

Tags: knockout.js

I have a list of addresses that I get through WepAPI using JSON, say:

```
data1 =
[ 
        {   address1  :"# 16  6 forks",   state:  'NC' },
        {   address1  :' 17 6 forks" ,     state:  'NY'},
        {   address1  :'18 forks",           state: 'AL'}
]
```

And also list of states like this:

```
data2 = [
     {id:1,shortname:'NY',fullname:'New York'},
     {id:2 ,shortname:'NC',fullname:'North Carolina'}
     {id:3 ,shortname:'AL',fullname:'ALabama'}
]
```

I get this data into address and state variables respectively like this:

```
if (data !== null) {
 for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
     self.addresses.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(data[i]));
  }
}
```

and state as

```
ko.utils.arrayPushAll(self.states, data);
```

My expectation is that when the html renders the appropriate state item in the address should be selected as initial value for e.g 'NC' in the case of first address but instead it displays 'NY' which is the first element in the state object.

While debugging I found that when the addresses variable gets assigned through ko.mappingfromJS it gets assigned as 'undefined' and then after this code when the states variable gets populated with state , the state of the top address gets assigned with the >first element from states object. This is what I observed by putting some console logs before and after address and state objects gets populated from JSON.

I am stuck here. Any help in this will be appreciated.

```html
<tbody>
   <td data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="arrow-down" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c">
   <td> 
     <select data-icon="arrow-down"
             data-bind="options: $root.states, 
                        value: state, 
                        optionsValue: 'shortstatename',
                        optionsText: 'statename', 
                        optionsCaption :' '">
      </select>
   </td>                   
   </td>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Where is `data` coming from, I see `data1` & `data2`?

Comment: i get it through ajax call from API and the mapp it to a array format

Comment: Can you show all the code?

Comment: This problem got solved for me now after changing the order I fetch the address and state objects from the server. I got the state object populated first and then the address object . However the problem seems to be with Ko.mapping.fromJS which was somehow making the address.state var to be undefined.It is worth mentioning that the address object had three address arrays each having same state .

Answer (score 0):

If your data really is:

```
data1 =
[ 
        {   address1  :'# 16  6 forks' ,      state:   'NC' },
        {   address1  :'17 6 forks" ,        state:   'NY'},
        {   address1  :'18 forks",            state:   'AL'}
]
```

it is malformed data, and will not behave well.  You have mismatched quotes (A `'` paired with a `"`) within it.

If it is just a typo, you should fix it in your question.